# Why is my listbox behaving unexpectedly? It is appending and not clearing

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am failing to see something... I have a listbox that updates from an ObservableCollection the collection is cleared then new data is added to it.

The listbox mmisbehaves it keeps the original collection data, then appends the new data to the bottom of the list, DESPITE the fact it is NOT in the ObservationalCollection. E.g. if it initally has 4 items in the listBox, if I clear the ItemsSource shortTerm and walk through the debugger, it does indeed clear, and then updates to have 6 new items. The listbox will then display the original 4 and append the new 6. It just keeps on appending and never clearing down the listbox!

THIS IS THE IMPORTANT BIT THAT MESSES WITH MY HEAD:  I wrote a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve, using fruit. And it works perfectly. I don't understand how doing the same thing, I tried re-creating the project in case there was something hidden in the background messing it up.

Why would one work and not the other when they do the same thing? This is driving me round the bend.

It keeps appending data to the listbox, despite the ObservableCollection being cleared. I don't understand why this is happening. It's updating my listbox, but not clearing previous data, I have spent several hours going through bindings and INotifyPropertyChanged and the same result keeps occuring.

I have tried to simplify, so I created a very basic program that just added 3 pieces of fruit to a listbox and pressing one button empties "fruit" and adds 3 new pieces in. The other button, clears it and puts in the original 3 pieces of fruit. So only 3 pieces of fruit appear in the listbox at any one time. (e.g Apple, Banana, Orange OR Mango, Peach, Pineapple).

Using the same steps if I do with my program, I get the results that pressing a button does clear the "fruitOC" ObservableCollection but DOES NOT clear the listbox and appends to it.

So if fruitOC is populated with Apple, Banana, Orange, so is the listbox, and of I press the button, it clears the fruitOC and adds the 3 new fruit Mango, Peach, Pineapple. But the listbox displays Apple, Banana, Orange, Mango, Peach, Pineapple.

I do not understand how this is happening! I don't see how it could be the binding as the code that works, only references setting the listBox's ItemsSource property and it works. My head hurts. I must be missing something but I cannot for the life of me get what it is!

I have tried to re-create the Visual Studio solution from scratch, in case there was something hidden away in the background and for my program, it just keeps appending!

```
// THIS CODE RESULTS IN THE LISTBOX APPENDING:
public ObservableCollection<string> shortTerm {get; set;}
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    shortTerm = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    listBoxShortTerm.ItemSource = shortTerm;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateShortTerm();

}

private void UpdateShortTerm()
{
    shortTerm.Clear(); // this bit works and clears all data
    shortTerm.Add("insert string here");
}

// THIS CODE THE LISTBOX WORKS AS EXPECTED:
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> fruit {get ; set;}
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            fruit = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            AddInitialFruit();
            listBoxFruit.ItemsSource = fruit;
        }

        private void AddInitialFruit()
        {
            fruit.Clear();
            fruit.Add("Apple");
            fruit.Add("Banana");
            fruit.Add("Orange");
        }
        private void ChangeFruit()
        {
            fruit.Clear();
            AddNewFruit();
        }

        private void AddNewFruit()
        {
            fruit.Add("Mango");
            fruit.Add("Peach");
            fruit.Add("Pineapple");
        }

        private void ButtonChangeFruit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeFruit();
        }

        private void ButtonChangeFruit2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddInitialFruit();
        }
    }
}
```

I only expect the listbox only to show the contents of my ObservableCollection shortTerm, not what is currently in along with what was previously contained in it.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you have. The posted code works as expected. Try to find what is different in your real code.

Comment: The only difference I can see is that "shortTerm" goes off to another procedure to get populated and comes back. If I try and do something like create a new ObservableCollection within a procedure and return that,e.g. shortTerm = CreateAndPopulateNewOC(); it causes the listBox to go blank and remain that way.

Comment: I have tried other methods such as creating a new OC with data e.g. newListData  = CreateAndPopulateNewOC(); and then try and shortTerm.Clear(); then foreach(string s in newListData) { shortTerm.Add(s) }; That just re-creates the constant appending issue. To make it worse, I added the fruit code into my program and ran it in the same buttons I use to update my program and it would behave as expected, but the original code for my program still meant the listBox was just appending.

Comment: I've also tried creating a new listbox and repopulating that. e.g. ListBox = CreateListBox(shortTerm); private ListBox CreateListBox(ObservableCollection o) { ListBox l = new ListBox(); l.ItemSource = o; return l; } What this does is just leave an empty listBox after pressing a button.

Comment: Can you post a complete program that duplicates your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrgh! I can't believe I never spotted this, it's been doing my head in for days! The issue was with a datatable in the background, not clearing down, thus the data taken from it to be put in the listbox kept appending, because the datatable kept appending.